# Integrate real data collected in an Excel sheet into the SUMO simulation

Tags: simulation, sumo, traffic-simulation, sumologic

I'm on a project on SUMO to simulate traffic use case . During this, I have collected real weather and traffic accident data in an Excel file, which I want to integrate into SUMO in order to measure traffic behavior.

I'm trying to convert my real data file from xls to XML and using --weather-file options to embed my data on XML file into SUMO :

`sumo -c network.net.xml -e 3600 --trip-files trip.trips.xml --weather-file meteo.xml --output-file simulation.sumo.out`

But it didn't work.

Is it the right way to add weather file to sumo ? and how about accident data ?

Can anyone help me integrate real data in xls or csv into SUMO ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: here it looks like all args are .xml

Comment: @Abel Yes the data to integrate also been convert to xml...it's not the right method ?

Comment: "trying to convert my real data file from xls to XML" + "been convert to xml" = already done? Maybe the issue is in your conversion? Make sure what you are trying to do works with a simpler dataset and then try to figure out what is different in the data structuring.

Comment: Hello @Abel thank you for your response. I redo the conversion with a dataset of 5 records, but I still have same problem. I also tried to insert weather file as additionnal files in the conf file like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <input>
        <net-file value="bassawarga.net.xml"/>
  <route-files value="bassawarga.rou.xml"/>
   <additional-files>
    meteo-data-test.xml
   </additional-files>
    </input>
 <output>
    <summary-output value="summary.out.xml"/>
   </output>
</configuration>

Comment: Find an example that works, even data that is part of a tutorial.